# Differences in function declarations in a Javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm confused about the different ways to declare functions inside a constructor function.

```
function ClassName() {
 this.one = function() {};
 var two = function() {};  
 three = function() {};
}
```

I know **one** is public and can be called by the outside and **two** is private. What are the semantics for **three**?

Comment: nice your points are 666 ... interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example as you have provided would be a syntax error, as you need to use `=` for assignment in that context.

`three` if used with the correct assignment operator would be a global function that would exist outside of that scope. When you omit the `var` keyword, the variable is assigned a property of the global object, which is `window` in a browser.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFNvK/).

When using `var`, they become properties of the *VariableObject* in the execution context. You use them as normal variables.

[Further Reading](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks! That cleared it up. I was thinking it was still part of the outer function since. jsFiddle is pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first format

this is closeer to the static methods in other programming languages.

```
var ClassName = {  
    one: function() {},
    two: function() {},
    three: function() {} 
}
```

ex:

```
  ClassName.one();
```

and the other is:

```
function ClassName(){  
    this.one = function() {};
    this.two = function() {};
    this.three = function() {}; 
}
```

here you can do:

```
var obj = new ClassName();
obj.one();
```

In this case you need to instantiate the object before using the methods.

These are the two ways for classes in javascript... that i know of.

Comment: You use commas between the members in an object literal, not semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

These are the ones that you can use in a constructor function:

```
function ClassName() {

  // A function assigned to a property
  this.one = function() {};

  // A function assigned to a local variable
  var two = function() {};

  // A function declared locally
  function three() {}

}
```

Only the first one ends up as a member of the object.

These are the ones that you can use in an object literal:

```
var objectName = {

  // A function assigned to a property
  one: function() {}

};
```